# Large file download in java incomplete without error

Tags: java, download, google-cloud-storage

we are downloading a very large file (~70G) but one one occasion the code completed without throwing an exception, but the downloaded file was incomplete, just under 50G.

The code is:

```
public void download(String url, String filename) throws Exception {
    URL dumpUrl = new URL(url);
    try (InputStream input = dumpUrl.openStream()) {
         Files.copy(input, Paths.get(filename));
    }
}
```

The `url` is a presigned Google Cloud Storage URL.

Is this just the libraries not detecting a connection reset issue? Or something else?

Are there better libraries I could use. Or do I need to do a HEAD call first and then match downloaded size against content-length.

Don't care that it didn't work, that happens and we have retry logic. My issue is the code thought it did work.

**UPDATE:** So it seems it failed at exactly 2 hours after starting download. This makes me suspect it may be netops/firewall issue. Not sure at which end, I'll hassle my ops team for starters. Anybody know of time limits at google's end?

Ignore this update - have more instances now, no set time. Anywhere between 20 minutes and 2 hours.

Comment: **What** is `inputStream` in `Files.copy(inputStream, Paths.get(filename));` ??? Why post imaginary code?

Comment: Fixed. It is two methods merged together, with some of our application specific crap removed

Comment: Most probably he didn't show full code, stripped sensitive piece of information and while doing so changed trivial naming of variables.

Comment: The thing is to show full code, if you are sure that code stripped wouldn't affect the logic of code, then it's OK, but how should we know that? Code as it is would work just fine.

Comment: Skipped code in second method creates parent directories for destination path if required. Did not want to distract from the point of the question.

Comment: Are you sure that you didn't get an exception? You're not showing what you do with exceptions, perhaps you're ignoring them somewhere higher up in your code, or you're logging them but you didn't find the logged error.

Comment: Yep, sure. The only catch is our generic job handling. effectively `try { run(); update(success); } catch { update(error) }`

Comment: You can't use openStream on a URL object that's a gs:// url, if that's what you're trying to do.  Java doesn't know how to deal with those.  I'd expect it to throw an exception.

Comment: I would never design software that tried to download a 70 GB file. Break the download into chunks of say 1 GB and then combine after the download. This allows you to retry failed parts. Depending on your Internet speed and reliability, anything larger than 1 GB should be broken into parts. The side benefit is faster downloads when you download more than one part at a time - up to about 4 parts at the same time.

Comment: It's hard to identify the problem without knowing what sort of client library or networking setup you have, but it's worth pointing out that Google Cloud Storage supports resumable downloading via standard HTTP range gets, so you should be able to tweak your code to not need to do the whole two hours over again.

Comment: The URL is a presigned https URL. We have no API access to the bucket itself. Will investigate the raged get option to break into chunks. Sounds like a good plan. As I said in update, I am expecting this issue to be firewall closing connection without a proper "reset".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never resolved core issue. But was able to workaround by comparing the bytes downloaded to the `Content-Length` header. Work in a loop which resumes incomplete download using the `Range` header (similar to `curl -C -`).